# Svn error, can update code, but cannot commit due to 403 forbidden error

Tags: svn, ubuntu

I can update code correctly, but cannot commit code. I get the following error when i try to commit code:

```
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Server sent unexpected return value (403 Forbidden) in response to MKACTIVITY request for '/site/!svn/act/080632f7-e62d-4987-96ce-88852bf86f46'
svn: Your commit message was left in a temporary file:
```

How can i resolve this error? i am using ubuntu 10 as my OS

Comment: Permissions issue. You might wanna hit server fault up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not using tortoisesvn or any other client, i was using the command line in unix to push code. I ended my day not being able to push code, when i came back and reattempted to push, it worked. I think the admins there did nothing to fix my problem. so it looks like i had to restart the pc to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Well it is obviously a server issue. Did you set up the svn server? How are you committing?

Answer (score 1):

Check your svn login and password. What svn client are you using? If it's TortoiseSVN, try deleting the url history and authentication. If you use a proxy server, make sure that your svn client is configured to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue for few hours and kept looking for the answer.
The end, I realized someone had added extra user 'Everyone' under the relevant folder with 'Read only' authority which caused all users within the folder couldn't update or commit.